# How do I display the result and remainder in ax and dx in Assembly (tasm)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I have the number 10 divided by 10, I wish to display the values, that are in ax, and dx, but TASM will not allow me to move ax, nor dx, into dl to display them side by side

```
    .model small
    .stack 100h
    .data
    Integer dw 5h
    Numbre dw 5h
    .code
    Start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,Integer
    mov bx,Numbre
    add ax,bx
    mov cx,10h
    mov dx,0h
    jmp compare
    compare : cmp ax,09
        ja divide
        jbe display_result
    divide : div cx
        add ax,"0"
        add dx,"0"
        jmp display_result_large
    display_result : add ax,"0"
        mov dl,ax
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h
        jmp endall
    display_result_large : mov dl,ax
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h
        mov dl,dx
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h
        jmp endall
    endall : mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
        end Start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dl` is an 8-bit register - `ax` and `dx` are 16-bit registers. You can access the low and high byte of `ax` as `al` and `ah`, and of `dx` as `dl` and `dh`. So instead of `mov dl, ax` you should use `mov dl,al`.

The instruction `mov dl,dx` would be replaced by `mov dl,dl`, but that would be a pointless operation. However, since you changed `dl`'s value when you did `mov dl,al` you'll have to save and restore it somehow. The easiest way would be to use the stack:

```
display_result_large :
    push dx    ; save dx on the stack
    mov dl,al
    mov ah,2h
    int 21h
    pop dx    ; restore dx's old value. the low byte of dx is dl, so
              ; the character is already in the correct register.
    mov ah,2h
    int 21h
    jmp endall
```

Comment: What exactly does pop, do? because now I get a displayed result of 0:

Comment: `push dx` corresponds to something like `sub sp,2; mov [sp],dx`, and `pop dx` corresponds to the opposite: `mov dx,[sp]; add sp,2`.

Comment: Note that you're not dividing by 10, you're dividing by 16: `mov cx,10h`

Comment: Thank You, I was not aware that 10 in hex was equal to 16

Comment: I'm going to try writing the in actual hex values

Comment: The Program has been created successfully and works perfectly, thanks for the input Michael.

Comment: The problem was that the ascii value was incorrect, since I was dividing by 16 and pointing towards the wrong registers.